# My script is reading my JSON file as empty when it's not?

Tags: python, json

Here is my config file:

```
{
"credentials":
  {
    "server": "0.1.2.3,6666",
    "database": "db", 
    "username": "user",
    "password": "password"
  }
}
```

Here is my python script in a separate file:

```
import pandas as pd
import datatest as dt
import datetime 
import json
import pyodbc

with open(r"path_to_config.json", 'r') as config_file:
    lines=config_file.readlines()
    df = json.load(config_file)

server=config_file['server']
database=config_file['database']
username=config_file['username']
password=config_file['password']

connection_string = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                                   'SERVER='+server+';'
                                   'DATABASE='+database+';'
                                   'UID='+username+';'
                                   'PWD='+password+';')
cursor = connection_string.cursor()

SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1"
cursor.execute(SQL_STATEMENT)

for i in cursor:
    print(i)
```

Here is my error:

```
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I've tried using json.loads(), I have tried creating a dictionary in my json file, I'm using readlines() and I've tried read() as well, I'm not sure what to do. My JSON file has data in it, not sure why the error is saying it expects data because it's right there. I think the issue lies where I am defining: `server=config_file['server']`

Comment: *because you are emptying the file*: `lines=config_file.readlines()` why did you do that? You don't use `lines` anywhere, and it doesn't seem like it would be of much use. Just remove that from your code

Comment: You are reading the file twice. Remove the `readlines()` call.

Comment: `lines=config_file.readlines()` read the entire file so there is nothing left (the file pointer is at the end of file) at `df = json.load(config_file)
`. Just remove that lines= ... part.

Comment: What is `config_file['server']` supposed to be? `config_file` is the file object, not a dictionary. And it was closed when the `with` block ended.

Comment: when I remove the "lines" variable, i get the error: "    server=config_file['server'] TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: the config_file['server'] is supposed to be there so pyodbc can read the config file's "server" key which is "0.1.2.3,6666". how else do i connect the config file's credentials to where pyodbc can read it?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've read run `readlines`, the stream has finished and is now empty!
If you need the `lines` for something, then you should load the json separately, for instance (*without* indentation):

```
df = json.load(open(r"path_to_config.json", 'r'))  # No indentation, outside the "with"
```

and if you *don't* need the `lines` variable, then don't run that line at all:

```
with open(r"path_to_config.json", 'r') as config_file:
    df = json.load(config_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `config_file.readlines()` you reach the end of the file, so `json.load(config_file)` has nothing to read.

You can add `config_file.seek(0)` before `json.load(config_file)` to get to the beginning of the file, or even better, just remove `lines = config_file.readlines()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `config_file.readlines()` it moves the "cursor" to the end of the file and thus there's nothing more to read when you call `json.load()`. You can either open the file again or just remove the `config_file.readlines()` call since its results are unused.